# Exactly what are those auto-complete sources?

Tags: auto-complete-mode

I've been looking for years for a documentation on those (in **bold**) [auto-complete](https://github.com/auto-complete) sources:

- ac-source-words-in-buffer
- **ac-source-abbrev**
- ac-source-dictionary
- ac-source-emacs-lisp-features
- **ac-source-features**
- ac-source-filename
- ac-source-files-in-current-dir
- *ac-source-functions*
- *ac-source-variables*
- *ac-source-symbols*
- ac-source-words-in-all-buffer
- ac-source-words-in-buffer
- ac-source-words-in-same-mode-buffers

Apparently, those in *italic* pertain to C (in which case I'm wondering why they're not suffixed as such) can somebody confirm this?

Comment: "abbrev" might be expansions for defined abbrevs (i.e. `abbrev.el`), and "features" might be `provide`d elisp features?

Comment: In any case, these are surely defined in the code somewhere, so why not find them and add those definitions to your question?